# How can I handle JSON response in Moqui inside a transition?

Tags: moqui

I am actually making a JSON-RPC call to a transition from AngularJS. As the content type of the request is **application/json**, the input parameters are automatically made available in the context so I don't need to handle it explicitly.

Here is my request to **'getUsers'** which is in the **'tutorial'** component.

```
function($scope, $http) {
    $http ({
        url: 'tutorial/getUsers',
        method: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({username:'demouser1'}),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    }).success(function(response){
        $scope.userList = response;
    });
}]);
```

The code for the transition is written below

```
<transition name="getUsers">
    <actions>
         <service-call name="Tutorial.PartyServices.get#Users" in-map="context"/>
    </actions>
    <default-response type="none"/>
</transition>
```

The service looks like this

```
<service verb="get" noun="Users">
    <in-parameters>
        <parameter name="username"/>
    </in-parameters>
    <actions>
        <entity-find entity-name="PersonAndUserAccount" list="userList">
            <search-form-inputs default-order-by="firstName,lastName,username"/>
            <econdition field-name="username" operator="equals" to-field-name="username"/>
        </entity-find>
        <script>ec.web.sendJsonResponse(userList)</script>
    </actions>
</service>
```

Now to send JSON response I wrote `ec.web.sendJsonResponse(userList)` in the service itself. This makes the service tightly coupled with service calls that expect JSON as response. If I want to internally call this service i.e. in Moqui I would have to define another service.

So my question is can I handle this response in the transition which is making this service call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the sample available for mentioning JSON response in transitions. You can refer ExampleApp.xml.

Here is the code snippet for your reference.

```
<transition name="ExampleEntity" method="post">
    <service-call name="org.moqui.example.ExampleServices.createExample" in-map="ec.web.parameters"
        web-send-json-response="true"/>
<default-response type="none"/>
</transition>
```

HTH.

Thanks